# Using Command Prompt to create Retina Vulnerability Report CSV

Tags: command-line, security, windows-server-2008-r2, batch-file, csv

I have scanned several computers on my network which have been flagged as needing certain fixes.  I am able to generate reports in Retina fine using the GUI report view, however, I would like to be able to create a report using CLI instead.  I have been told that it goes much quicker.

I found references online that all linked back to Retina's User Guide, which can be found [here](http://forums.eeye.com/index.php?/topic/2190-automation-of-report-generating/?p=7926), but the examples that they list leave a little bit to be desired. (I.e. They have no specific examples for /rptvulncsv, also, why do they add in Hyphens in the examples, but not in the topmost part?)

> Retina /rpttype target rtd [jobname]
>
> ...
>
> Example:
>
> Retina /rptexec ―c:\reports\executive\WAN_exec.html ―c:\program files\eeye digital
> security\retina 5\scans\network.rtd ―WAN

Here's the process that I've been following:

```
Start -> cmd -> Right-click, Run as Administrator

"C:\Program Files (x86)\eEye Digital Security\Retina 5\Retina.exe" /rptvulncsv "C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\TEST\Test.csv" "C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\TEST\File_Name.rtd" "C:\Users\MyAccount\Desktop\TEST\#########_RetinaJob.xml"
```

Here's the error message that I've been getting:

> Can not use this database for output: Unknown Database Type - Error: GetEeyeDatabaseVersion of DataSource::Database Type= - -... [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I've tried to move around the order of the "target", "rtd" and "jobname" but I keep getting cryptic error messages which all just link back to the same forum post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of troubleshooting this on and off when I had a chance, I was able to find a solution:

First, navigate to the folder that retina.exe is residing within:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\eEye Digital Security\Retina 5
```

Next, you want to launch the Retina.exe, tell Retina the type of report you want to have generated, tell Retina where this newly created file will be stored and what it should be called (don't forget to include the .csv extension in the filename!). Finally, you want to tell Retina where the already-created RTD file is located.  I created a folder on the desktop and copied/pasted an RTD from C:\Program Files (x86)\eEye Digital Security\Retina 5\Scans to avoid any possible permissions issues or issues with spacing:

```
retina.exe /rptvulncsv C:\Users\USERNAMEHERE\Desktop\TEST_Folder\Test.csv C:\Users\USERNAMEHERE\Desktop\Test_Folder\Test_CLI_Scan.rtd
```